# God appearing to non-believers

Tags: bible

I just want to know what bible verse is it that talks about God appearing to a group of non-believers and even after seeing God they still didn't believe.

Comment: This question asks to find a specific Bible verse, and will probably be closed because "verse search" questions are not considered on topic here. D J Clayworth has identified the specific verse I think you're looking for. If you wish to know more about the details of that story, feel free to ask a more targeted question. It may be helpful to look at the [tour] and the [help] for the site.

Comment: I have just added another Bible text to my answer that my help

Answer (score 3):

Here is a text - Rom 1:18-25 that describes people who know God but refuse to obey him and thus become depraved.  V21, 22 summarises this:

> For even though they knew God, they did not honor Him as God or give
>   thanks, but they became futile in their speculations, and their
>   foolish heart was darkened. 22Professing to be wise, they became
>   fools

Here are three more (radical) suggestions that answer the question but may not satisfy the question(!?!)

1. Judas Iscariot met and knew Jesus (while on earth but who was still God, John 1:18, 5:17, 18, 20:28, etc) but later, betrayed Jesus and then went out and hanged himself.
2. The rich young ruler, Matt 18:18-25, who went away very sad because he loved his riches more than Jesus.
3. There is also the instance in Rev 6:15-17 where the wicked see Jesus (the "Lamb" on the throne) and ask to be destroyed because they do not want to be in His presence.

In all these cases, the people know and recognise God but refuse to have Him as their God.

Comment: In all three cases, the recipients did actually believe they had seen God. But they chose not to believe _in_ God. This is valuable as it shows that intellectually knowing is not the same as true faith.

Comment: Just to mention that the rich young ruler may, at a later stage, have realised Jesus was God incarnate after the resurrection, and he may have believed then. The Bible does not say, but neither does it say that walking away from Jesus very sad, before Jesus had died, was his final state.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an exact fit, but you may be thinking about the parable of the Rich Man and Lazarus. It's found in [the Gospel of Luke, chapter 16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2016%3A19-31&version=NIV).

In the parable, the Rich Man dies unbelieving and goes to Hell (Hades). He asks that Lazarus (who is also dead) be sent to warn his family so that they will not suffer the same fate, since they will believe if someone returns from the dead. He is told that if his family do not believe the prophets, then they will also not believe even if someone returns from the dead.

Most Christians would take the parable as a symbolic story rather than a historical occurrence, but it does describe a supernatural appearance which is not believed.

Comment: Think you got the right quote (place) that the OP was thinking of. +1

Comment: This describes someone who is _not_ God and their _not_ appearing to non-believers.

Comment: @NigelJ You are absolutely right. But I still think it's probably the passage the questioner was thinking of :-)

Answer (score 1):

God is a spirit, says Jesus, John 4:24. He has no visible form, of himself. Therefore if he 'appears' to a person on earth, it is to *faith* that he is appearing.

If a person is an unbeliever, or, as you say a 'non-believer', there is no faith there to which God may appear.

God *has appeared*, in manifestation, in the Person of the Son, Jesus Christ. Multitudes saw him - and many did not believe that he was whom he truly was. But some did believe. They believed that Jesus Christ - in manifest form - was the Son of God.

But many, though they saw miracles and were impressed, did not believe in Him.

God himself, the Father and the Son (who are one, for Jesus said "I and my Father are One, John 10:30) are seen by faith, not natural sight.

---

In Acts 9:7 and Acts 22:9 we read of men accompanying Saul of Tarsus when he was overwhelmed by a light and he heard a voice. The men also are reported to have seen the light (but were not, like Saul, blinded by it) and to have been aware of a voice but were not able to report the speech of the voice.

Only Saul, later Paul, believed in Jesus Christ because of this incident.

Perhaps this is the text in the memory of the OP.

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually answer the question.

Comment: @DJClayworth If the question is not valid, then there is no answer to it.